# Windows 10 boot up is virtually unresponsive

Tags: boot, windows-10

**Problem:**

My windows 10 is getting caught in a boot sequence that takes up to 6-hours

**Solutions I have tried:**

- Running antiviruses including bitdefender 2015, malwarebytes, windows defender, iobits anti-malware, and avast
- Running full scans of all types in CC-cleaner, advanced systemcare, and wise 365.
- Running windows 10 start up repair using a windows media disk
- CHDSK
- Running registry cleaners/repair tools of all types such as windows regrepair, advanced systemcares reg cleaner, CC-cleaner reg tool, and wise's reg tool
- Enabling fast start up in control panel

**Explanation:**

So I upgraded to windows 10 the day it was released and everything went pretty smoothly. However a month or so ago it became infected by a virus that downloaded countless other viruses, my solution to this was to use bitdefender and advanced systemcare to clear my system of the viruses but by the time i deleted them the damage was done.

My windows 10 gets caught in a boot up sequence that takes up 6-hours just to reach the login screen. After trying to google it I ended up reinstalling windows 10 and losing all of my files in the process but hey it fixed my problem.

But yesterday the problem returned. Which leads me to believe its not a virus. I don't want to clean install again and lose all my files. Any ideas on what I can do to fix my problem?

Comment: The first step before I provide any possible solutions is for you to backup your personal files.

Comment: I already have everything backed up onto a external hard drive